# UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to display a UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell.

Inside method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    CGSize cellSize = cell.frame.size;
    CGFloat cellWidth = cellSize.width;
    CGFloat cellHeight = cellSize.height;

    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, cellHeight);
    UIImageView * image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"cyan.jpg"]];

    CGRect nameFrame = CGRectMake(80, 0, cellWidth-80, cellHeight/2);
    UILabel * nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameFrame];
    nameLabel.text = @"Name: John Doe";

    CGRect jobFrame = CGRectMake(80, 20, cellWidth-80, cellHeight/2);
    UILabel * jobLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:jobFrame];
    jobLabel.text = @"Job: IT-Consultant";

    [cell addSubview:image];
    [cell addSubview:nameLabel];
    [cell addSubview:jobLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

The labels are displaying perfectly but I don't see the image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two things: 1) UITableViewCell already has a UIImageView in it, that you can access through the `imageView` property - just in case that helps in your case, and  2) can you display the image somewhere else to verify that it does in fact load and display correctly and that the error occurs when adding it to a cell?

Comment: 1) `imageView` is not assignable. 2) I did not try that. Will give it a try.

Comment: 1) Correct, but `imageView.image` is assignable. 2) Let me know if it works, and good luck :)

Comment: 1) Didn't work, probably because of 2. 2) I did as gschandler said and changed the background of the imageview. Now I can see that the view is exactly where I expect it to be, but there is not image in it. So that means that the image never loads. I tried to load another image, tried even png, tried to first load it into NSData and then to UIImage, nothing worked. This is very strange.

Comment: Please don’t use the cocoa tag for Cocoa Touch questions. Use the cocoa-touch tag instead.

Comment: Does the image load if you add it to some other view that's not a UITableCell?

Comment: Fixed. Needed to use `imageNamed:` instead of `imageWithContentsOfFile:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`imageWithContentsOfFile:` expects a path to be sent to it. Use `imageNamed:` instead, or get hold of the path first by using `NSBundle`'s pathForResource... methods first to get the path.

Also, if the image is the same for every cell, you should add the image view inside the cell=nil block, or you will be adding the view over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the `UITableViewCell` contentView instead.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:...];
```

Comment: Did it but still got the same problem. The labels display but not the image.

Comment: Check your various subview autoreisizingMasks. Make sure they aren't covering each other when the cell resizes, which it will do after being added to the table. When I have subview issues, I make each subview's backgroundColor a different, bright color to make sure the view is where I expect it, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. I changed the color of the background and now I can clearly see that the uiimageview is exactly where I expect it to be. So the problem must be that the image wont load. Will look more into that.

Comment: Are your images added to your project so they get properly copied into your bundle? That one often bites me.

Comment: Also note that your original code for loading the image requires a full path, not just a file name. `[UIImage imageNamed:]` needs the image to be in the bundle, whereas `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` is expecting a full path.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UITableViewCell's imageView property instead of what you're doing. To be more clear, use cell.imageView.image and set your UIImage to that.

Or if you wish the image's location to be more flexible, add the imageView to the cell's contentView. i.e: [cell.contentView addSubview:yourImageView];

Comment: The `imageView` property is not assignable. If you meant the `image` property, it is deprecated. I tried setting the `contentView` as well, still got the same problem. The labels display but not the image.